# InternetExplorer Com Object, getElementById, getElementsByName and getElementsByTagName

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, powershell-2.0, comobject

I want to create a webtest with PowerShell.
At the moment I had a problem with a SharePoint Textbox when I create a new Calender entry.
The properties from the Field are:

Now you can see, there is no fixed ID that can I use.

**It is possible to search the the word "Titel" and get the ID?**

(title = titel because it is german ;-) )

The following code is not working.

```
$ie2.Document.getElementById( "*ctl00$TextField").value = "test"
$ie2.Document.getElementByName( "*ctl00$TextField").value = "test"
$ie2.Document.getElementByTagName( "Titel").value = "test"
```

Sourcecode in the Internet Explorer:

```
<td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <nobr>Titel<span class="ms-formvalidation" title="Dies ist ein Pflichtfeld." > *</span></nobr>
    </h3></td>
        <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
        <!-- FieldName="Titel"
             FieldInternalName="Title"
             FieldType="SPFieldText"
          -->
            <span dir="none">
        <input name="ctl00$m$g_27855e01_08c1_498d_b130_0b761c472fbd$ctl00$ctl05$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$TextField" type="text" maxlength="255" id="ctl00_m_g_27855e01_08c1_498d_b130_0b761c472fbd_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" title="Titel" class="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true" /><br />
    </span>
```

Comment: You should post the HTML snippet you are trying to access, plus how it should look like when you are done.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak for your Comment! I want to create a new Calender entry in SharePoint. I edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using [WATIN from PowerShell](http://poshcode.org/2434), WATIN would make your life much easier.

Comment: can we simulate a drag and drop with watin?

Comment: Actually, nowadays I think I'd recommend using Selenium, since Watin pretty much died out (the last release was in April 2011, and the last check-in a year later).

Selenium has a thriving community and there are several frameworks and language adapters for using it with PowerShell (even https://sepsx.codeplex.com/)